# How do I determine if the user who registered is not spam?

Tags: plugins, security, bbpress

I've recently set up a forum on my site with the bbpress-plugin. Now a user has registered on the site but the email-adress looks suspicious to me. How can I determine if the user is real? Is there a security risk if it is spam and I do not remove the user? Thanks

Comment: Check how the user engage with your board. I would suggest that you add a 'Newly Registered Users' type of role that they get where they have to for instance have 3 posts before they are regular members. And within this role, you can have different types of restrictions, such as delay between posts, no links within posts etc. Fight spam by trying to defeat their agenda. There is no other way because spam can be posted by both bots and humans.

Comment: My suggestion would be to add Captcha to your registration page to slow / limit spam bots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Require that emails be verified before registration is completed.
- Captcha
- Use Honeypot Project
- Install Akismet
- Require Facebook, Twitter, or another service for registration.

You won't be able to stop all spam but you can fight the majority of them.